# Converting wiki pages to modern pages with Pnp PowerShell creates pages with links to Previous_xxx.aspx

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, pnp-powershell, modern-pages, wiki-pages

I am using the PnP PowerShell script `Convert-WikiAndWebPartPages.ps1` (with the switch 'Modern page takes source page name' set to true), from [Transforming to modern site pages using PowerShell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/transform/modernize-userinterface-site-pages-powershell), to convert site pages to modern pages.

But I am running into an issue with the migrated wiki pages. The pages contain links to the other pages, but after the conversion the links in the modern pages are pointing to `Previous_xxx.aspx`.

So after the conversion to modern pages all links need to be fixed to the original source page name (and I would like to keep the page creation/modification info).

Which PnP PowerShell commands can I use to correct the links?

Comment: How do you point to another page in the wikipage? Do you use ‘a’ element?

Comment: Yes, but it is wiki pages so the user just enclose the word to link in brackets `[]`. But if I check View source in the original files it is like: `<a class="ms-wikilink" href="/sites/AAA/wiki/Wiki%20Pages/Test%20Information.aspx">` . And in the converted files it is like: `\u003ca class=\\\"ms-missinglink\\\" href=\\\"/sites/AAA/SitePages/Previous_Test%20Information.aspx\\\"\u003e`

Answer (score 1):

With the switch `-TakeSourcePageName:$true` I kept getting faulty links inside the migrated pages (pointing to `Previous_xxx.aspx`.), and I do not know how to correct that with PnP. This issue with `-TakeSourcePageName:$true` was very reproducible, even after I changed the locale.

So, as a workaround, I used `-TakeSourcePageName:$false`, which did not have the issue with faulty links, but created files named `Migrated_*.aspx`, which I did not want. I wrote the following script to rename them to their original names. (I do not need any backup of the old files, since I could just get new files with ShareGate from my old SharePoint on-prem site if I wanted to migrate them again).

This is the renaming script (which could probably be written as a one-liner..):

````
    $pages = Get-PnPListItem -List sitepages -PageSize 500 | Where {$_["FileLeafRef"] -like "Migrated_*.aspx"}
    Write-Host "Pages are fetched, let's start the renaming..." -ForegroundColor Green
    Foreach($page in $pages){
        $newpage = $page["FileLeafRef"] -replace ‘Migrated_’
        Rename-PnPFile -ServerRelativeUrl $page["FileRef"] -TargetFileName $newpage -OverwriteIfAlreadyExists -Force
    }

    Write-Host "Renaming done!" -ForegroundColor Green```
````

Comment: Unfortunately I do not get to keep the page creation/modification info this way.

Answer (score 0):

I can not reproduce your issue with this cmdlet [ConvertTo-PnPClientSidePage](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/convertto-pnpclientsidepage?view=sharepoint-ps).

My test result:
[image]

Comment: I can see in the screenshot that your page starts with  `Migrated_ `. Since I use `-TakeSourcePageName:$true` I do not get any pages with that name. Are you suggesting using  `-TakeSourcePageName:$false` as a workaround?  I am using `SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline 3.26.2010.0`

Comment: According to my test, this attribute in the command will not affect the result.

Comment: The issue with `-TakeSourcePageName:$true` is very reproducible on my side. Even if I change settings like locale and sort order from Swedish to English, I get links pointing to `Previous_xxx.aspx` in the migrated pages. But with  `-TakeSourcePageName:$false` the links are correct in the `Migrated_xxx.aspx` page. So a workaround for me could be to use `-TakeSourcePageName:$false` instead and then write some scripts renaming the pages to their proper names.